# Why it is so difficult to pass this &mut db transaction to this closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm using the below code in my real project. (Obviously this is simplified and one file only for playground.)

[Rust explorer playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Aasync-trait%20%3D%20%220.1.61%22%0Asqlx%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%220.6.2%22%2C%20default-features%20%3D%20false%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%22macros%22%2C%0A%20%20%22postgres%22%2C%0A%20%20%22runtime-tokio-native-tls%22%2C%0A%20%20%22time%22%2C%0A%5D%20%7D%0Atokio%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%221.24.1%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22full%22%5D%20%7D%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3A%7Bfuture%3A%3AFuture%2C%20pin%3A%3APin%2C%20sync%3A%3AArc%7D%3B%0A%0Apub%20trait%20Trait%3A%20Send%20%2B%20Sync%20%2B%20Player%20%2B%20Shirt%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3A%20Player%20%2B%20Shirt%3E%20Trait%20for%20T%20%7B%7D%0A%0Apub%20type%20Lambda%3C%27a%2C%20ArgT%2C%20ResT%3E%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20dyn%20Fn(ArgT)%20-%3E%20Pin%3CBox%3Cdyn%20Future%3COutput%20%3D%20Result%3CResT%2C%20String%3E%3E%20%2B%20Send%20%2B%20%27a%3E%3E%20%2B%20Sync%20%2B%20%27a%3B%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Apub%20trait%20Player%3A%20Send%20%2B%20Sync%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20player_create%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_input%3A%20%26PlayerInput%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lambda%3A%20%26Lambda%3C%27_%2C%20PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%3C%27a%3E%2C%20DomainPlayer%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3CDomainPlayer%2C%20String%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Apub%20trait%20Shirt%3A%20Send%20%2B%20Sync%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20shirt_get_next_and_increase%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tx%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20sqlx%3A%3APgConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3Ci64%2C%20String%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20pool%3A%20Arc%3Csqlx%3A%3APgPool%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new(pool%3A%20Arc%3Csqlx%3A%3APgPool%3E)%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%20%7B%20pool%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Aimpl%20Player%20for%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20player_create%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_input%3A%20%26PlayerInput%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lambda%3A%20%26Lambda%3C%27_%2C%20PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%3C%27a%3E%2C%20DomainPlayer%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3CDomainPlayer%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20tx%20%3D%20self.pool.begin().await.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20_input%20here%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20shirt_next_value%20%3D%20Box%3A%3Anew(%7Cmodel%3A%20String%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%3A%3AShirt%3A%3Ashirt_get_next_and_increase(self%2C%20%26mut%20tx%2C%20model)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20domain_player%20%3D%20lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%20%7B%20shirt_next_value%20%7D).await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sqlx%3A%3Aquery_as%3A%3A%3C_%2C%20DomainPlayer%3E(%22INSERT%20INTO%20player%20(...)%20VALUES%20(...)%20RETURNING%20*%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.bind(domain_player.id)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.bind(domain_player.shirt_number)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.fetch_one(%26mut%20*tx)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.await%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(res)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Aimpl%20Shirt%20for%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20shirt_get_next_and_increase%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_tx%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20sqlx%3A%3APgConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_model%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3Ci64%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Here%20I%27m%20awaiting%20an%20async%20call%20for%20DB%20operations%20using%20the%20same%20DB%20transacion%20of%20the%20caller%20(_tx)...%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20_tx%20here...%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20123%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(res)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Needs%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20command_pg_repo%3A%20Arc%3Cdyn%20Trait%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Default)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20PlayerInput%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20id%3A%20String%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug%2C%20Default%2C%20Clone%2C%20sqlx%3A%3AFromRow)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20DomainPlayer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20id%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20shirt_number%3A%20i64%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20needed%20fields%20here%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20shirt_next_value%3A%20Box%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dyn%20FnMut(String)%20-%3E%20Pin%3CBox%3Cdyn%20Future%3COutput%20%3D%20Result%3Ci64%2C%20String%3E%3E%20%2B%20Send%20%2B%20%27a%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20Send%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20Sync%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20%27a%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Handler%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20needs%3A%20Arc%3CNeeds%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Handler%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new(needs%3A%20Arc%3CNeeds%3E)%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%20%7B%20needs%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20async%20fn%20handle(%26self%2C%20input%3A%20%26PlayerInput)%20-%3E%20Result%3CDomainPlayer%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20self%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.needs%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.command_pg_repo%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.player_create(%26input%2C%20%26%7Cmut%20args%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20input%20%3D%20input%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Apin(async%20move%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20shirt_number%20%3D%20(args.shirt_next_value)(%22player%22.to_string()).await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20o%20%3D%20DomainPlayer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20input.id.to_string()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shirt_number%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(o)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(res)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20main()%20-%3E%20Result%3C()%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20db_conn%20%3D%20sqlx%3A%3APgPool%3A%3Aconnect(%22fake_url%22).await.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20pg_repo%20%3D%20Arc%3A%3Anew(Repo%3A%3Anew(Arc%3A%3Anew(db_conn)))%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20needs%20%3D%20Arc%3A%3Anew(Needs%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20command_pg_repo%3A%20pg_repo%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20handler%20%3D%20Handler%3A%3Anew(needs)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20new_player_input%20%3D%20PlayerInput%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22abc%22.to_string()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20player%20%3D%20handler.handle(%26new_player_input).await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20dbg!(player)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(())%0A%7D%0A)

As you can see I'm trying to use a sqlx Transaction from one function to a closure.

But I'm stucked.

I don't even know if this (so common Golang pattern) is the best wat to do in Rust. But at least it should work now.

```rust
use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin, sync::Arc};

pub trait Trait: Send + Sync + Player + Shirt {}

impl<T: Player + Shirt> Trait for T {}

pub type Lambda<'a, ArgT, ResT> =
    dyn Fn(ArgT) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<ResT, String>> + Send + 'a>> + Sync + 'a;

#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait Player: Send + Sync {
    async fn player_create<'a>(
        &'a self,
        _input: &PlayerInput,
        lambda: &Lambda<'_, PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'a>, DomainPlayer>,
    ) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String>;
}

#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait Shirt: Send + Sync {
    async fn shirt_get_next_and_increase<'a>(
        &'a self,
        tx: &'a mut sqlx::PgConnection,
        model: String,
    ) -> Result<i64, String>;
}

pub struct Repo {
    pub pool: Arc<sqlx::PgPool>,
}

impl Repo {
    pub fn new(pool: Arc<sqlx::PgPool>) -> Self {
        Self { pool }
    }
}

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Player for Repo {
    async fn player_create<'a>(
        &'a self,
        _input: &PlayerInput,
        lambda: &Lambda<'_, PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'a>, DomainPlayer>,
    ) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String> {
        let mut tx = self.pool.begin().await.unwrap();

        // use _input here

        let shirt_next_value = Box::new(|model: String| {
            self::Shirt::shirt_get_next_and_increase(self, &mut tx, model)
        });

        let domain_player = lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs { shirt_next_value }).await?;

        let res =
            sqlx::query_as::<_, DomainPlayer>("INSERT INTO player (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *")
                .bind(domain_player.id)
                .bind(domain_player.shirt_number)
                .fetch_one(&mut *tx)
                .await
                .unwrap();

        Ok(res)
    }
}

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Shirt for Repo {
    async fn shirt_get_next_and_increase<'a>(
        &'a self,
        _tx: &'a mut sqlx::PgConnection,
        _model: String,
    ) -> Result<i64, String> {
        // Here I'm awaiting an async call for DB operations using the same DB transacion of the caller (_tx)...

        // use _tx here...

        let res = 123;

        Ok(res)
    }
}

pub struct Needs {
    pub command_pg_repo: Arc<dyn Trait>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct PlayerInput {
    pub id: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct DomainPlayer {
    pub id: String,
    pub shirt_number: i64,
}

pub struct PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'a> {
    // other needed fields here
    pub shirt_next_value: Box<
        dyn FnMut(String) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<i64, String>> + Send + 'a>>
            + Send
            + Sync
            + 'a,
    >,
}

pub struct Handler {
    needs: Arc<Needs>,
}

impl Handler {
    pub fn new(needs: Arc<Needs>) -> Self {
        Self { needs }
    }

    pub async fn handle(&self, input: &PlayerInput) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String> {
        let res = self
            .needs
            .command_pg_repo
            .player_create(&input, &|mut args| {
                let input = input;

                Box::pin(async move {
                    let shirt_number = (args.shirt_next_value)("player".to_string()).await?;

                    let o = DomainPlayer {
                        id: input.id.to_string(),
                        shirt_number,
                    };

                    Ok(o)
                })
            })
            .await?;

        Ok(res)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let db_conn = sqlx::PgPool::connect("fake_url").await.unwrap();

    let pg_repo = Arc::new(Repo::new(Arc::new(db_conn)));

    let needs = Arc::new(Needs {
        command_pg_repo: pg_repo,
    });

    let handler = Handler::new(needs);

    let new_player_input = PlayerInput {
        id: "abc".to_string(),
    };

    let player = handler.handle(&new_player_input).await?;

    dbg!(player);

    Ok(())
}
```

The error:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:62:13
   |
57 |         let mut tx = self.pool.begin().await.unwrap();
   |             ------ variable defined here
...
61 |         let shirt_next_value = Box::new(|model: String| {
   |                                                       - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
62 |             self::Shirt::shirt_get_next_and_increase(self, &mut tx, model)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--^^^^^^^^
   |             |                                                   |
   |             |                                                   variable captured here
   |             returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape

error[E0597]: `tx` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:62:65
   |
55 |         lambda: &Lambda<'_, PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'a>, DomainPlayer>,
   |         ------ lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `lambda`
...
61 |         let shirt_next_value = Box::new(|model: String| {
   |                                         --------------- value captured here
62 |             self::Shirt::shirt_get_next_and_increase(self, &mut tx, model)
   |                                                                 ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
65 |         let domain_player = lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs { shirt_next_value }).await?;
   |                                                             ---------------- this usage requires that `tx` is borrowed for `'1`
...
76 |     }
   |     - `tx` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `tx` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:71:34
   |
55 |         lambda: &Lambda<'_, PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'a>, DomainPlayer>,
   |         ------ lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `lambda`
...
61 |         let shirt_next_value = Box::new(|model: String| {
   |                                         --------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
62 |             self::Shirt::shirt_get_next_and_increase(self, &mut tx, model)
   |                                                                 -- first borrow occurs due to use of `tx` in closure
...
65 |         let domain_player = lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs { shirt_next_value }).await?;
   |                                                             ---------------- this usage requires that `tx` is borrowed for `'1`
...
71 |                 .fetch_one(&mut *tx)
   |                                  ^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0499, E0597.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

Comment: Try to annotate the lifetime explicitly for lambda, _input and tx

Comment: I do not understand... Can you write an example? You can use the Rust Explorer...

Comment: I see many issues in the code, really cannot help you to fix it. I suggest to annotate the lifetime and try to reason about them.

First of all,  this line `self::Shirt::shirt_get_next_and_increase(self, &mut tx, model)`, the lifetime of `self` is 'a and `tx` is a stack value within the method, its reference cannot outlive 'a

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to understand how to fix. Hence the question. Given your experience and the rust explorer link I think it takes you 10 seconds to figure out the problem. It takes me a "lifetime". LOL

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main issues with the code (more like 2 and a half):

1. Closures cannot return references to things the closure owns, or things the closure borrowed mutably (More formally: the return type of the `Fn*` function/closure family of traits cannot borrow from the closure type itself). One way to fix this is to have `tx` be moved into the closure, and then moved into the closure's returned `Future`. Shared ownership can be achieved with `std::sync::Arc`, and cloning it and moving it when you need to give another task ownership.
2. `Fn` closures may be called concurrently, so they cannot use mutable references to things the closure owns or has borrowed, but this code tries to use a `&mut tx` borrowing from the outer scope inside a `Fn` closure. (This issue is bypassed with the solution outlined below).
3. If you want to access something mutably when it is shared, you need to synchronize those accesses so only one thing can actually access it at a time. One way to do this in async Rust is using `tokio::sync::Mutex`.

Combining the above, putting `tx` into a `Arc<Mutex<...>>`, moving `.clone()`s of the `Arc` into the tasks that need ownership, and `.lock().await`ing whenever you need to access it mutably may fix your problem (it makes it compile at least).

[Rust explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Aasync-trait%20%3D%20%220.1.61%22%0Asqlx%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%220.6.2%22%2C%20default-features%20%3D%20false%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%22macros%22%2C%0A%20%20%22postgres%22%2C%0A%20%20%22runtime-tokio-native-tls%22%2C%0A%20%20%22time%22%2C%0A%5D%20%7D%0Atokio%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%221.24.1%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22full%22%5D%20%7D%0A*%2F%0Ause%20std%3A%3A%7Bfuture%3A%3AFuture%2C%20pin%3A%3APin%2C%20sync%3A%3AArc%7D%3B%0A%0Ause%20tokio%3A%3Async%3A%3AMutex%3B%0A%0Apub%20trait%20Trait%3A%20Send%20%2B%20Sync%20%2B%20Player%20%2B%20Shirt%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3A%20Player%20%2B%20Shirt%3E%20Trait%20for%20T%20%7B%7D%0A%0Apub%20type%20Lambda%3C%27a%2C%20ArgT%2C%20ResT%3E%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20dyn%20Fn(ArgT)%20-%3E%20Pin%3CBox%3Cdyn%20Future%3COutput%20%3D%20Result%3CResT%2C%20String%3E%3E%20%2B%20Send%20%2B%20%27a%3E%3E%20%2B%20Sync%20%2B%20%27a%3B%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Apub%20trait%20Player%3A%20Send%20%2B%20Sync%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20player_create%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_input%3A%20%26PlayerInput%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lambda%3A%20%26Lambda%3C%27_%2C%20PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%3C%27a%3E%2C%20DomainPlayer%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3CDomainPlayer%2C%20String%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Apub%20trait%20Shirt%3A%20Send%20%2B%20Sync%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20shirt_get_next_and_increase%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tx%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20sqlx%3A%3APgConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3Ci64%2C%20String%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20pool%3A%20Arc%3Csqlx%3A%3APgPool%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new(pool%3A%20Arc%3Csqlx%3A%3APgPool%3E)%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%20%7B%20pool%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Aimpl%20Player%20for%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20player_create%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_input%3A%20%26PlayerInput%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lambda%3A%20%26Lambda%3C%27_%2C%20PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%3C%27a%3E%2C%20DomainPlayer%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3CDomainPlayer%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tx%20%3D%20Arc%3A%3Anew(Mutex%3A%3Anew(self.pool.begin().await.unwrap()))%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20_input%20here%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20shirt_next_value%20%3D%20Box%3A%3Anew(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tx%20%3D%20tx.clone()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20move%20%7Cmodel%3A%20String%7C%20-%3E%20Pin%3CBox%3Cdyn%20Future%3COutput%20%3D%20Result%3Ci64%2C%20std%3A%3Astring%3A%3AString%3E%3E%20%2B%20Send%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tx%20%3D%20tx.clone()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Apin(async%20move%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%3A%3AShirt%3A%3Ashirt_get_next_and_increase(self%2C%20%26mut%20*tx.lock().await%2C%20model)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.await%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20domain_player%20%3D%20lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%20%7B%20shirt_next_value%20%7D).await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sqlx%3A%3Aquery_as%3A%3A%3C_%2C%20DomainPlayer%3E(%22INSERT%20INTO%20player%20(...)%20VALUES%20(...)%20RETURNING%20*%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.bind(domain_player.id)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.bind(domain_player.shirt_number)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.fetch_one(%26mut%20*tx.lock().await)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.await%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(res)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Basync_trait%3A%3Aasync_trait%5D%0Aimpl%20Shirt%20for%20Repo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20async%20fn%20shirt_get_next_and_increase%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20self%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_tx%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20sqlx%3A%3APgConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_model%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3Ci64%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Here%20I%27m%20awaiting%20an%20async%20call%20for%20DB%20operations%20using%20the%20same%20DB%20transacion%20of%20the%20caller%20(_tx)...%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20_tx%20here...%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20123%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(res)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Needs%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20command_pg_repo%3A%20Arc%3Cdyn%20Trait%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Default)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20PlayerInput%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20id%3A%20String%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug%2C%20Default%2C%20Clone%2C%20sqlx%3A%3AFromRow)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20DomainPlayer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20id%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20shirt_number%3A%20i64%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20PlayerCreateLambdaArgs%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20needed%20fields%20here%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20shirt_next_value%3A%20Box%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dyn%20Fn(String)%20-%3E%20Pin%3CBox%3Cdyn%20Future%3COutput%20%3D%20Result%3Ci64%2C%20String%3E%3E%20%2B%20Send%20%2B%20%27a%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20Send%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20Sync%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20%27a%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Handler%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20needs%3A%20Arc%3CNeeds%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Handler%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new(needs%3A%20Arc%3CNeeds%3E)%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%20%7B%20needs%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20async%20fn%20handle(%26self%2C%20input%3A%20%26PlayerInput)%20-%3E%20Result%3CDomainPlayer%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20self%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.needs%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.command_pg_repo%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.player_create(%26input%2C%20%26%7Cargs%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20input%20%3D%20input%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Apin(async%20move%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20shirt_number%20%3D%20(args.shirt_next_value)(%22player%22.to_string()).await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20o%20%3D%20DomainPlayer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20input.id.to_string()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shirt_number%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(o)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(res)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20main()%20-%3E%20Result%3C()%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20db_conn%20%3D%20sqlx%3A%3APgPool%3A%3Aconnect(%22fake_url%22).await.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20pg_repo%20%3D%20Arc%3A%3Anew(Repo%3A%3Anew(Arc%3A%3Anew(db_conn)))%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20needs%20%3D%20Arc%3A%3Anew(Needs%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20command_pg_repo%3A%20pg_repo%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20handler%20%3D%20Handler%3A%3Anew(needs)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20new_player_input%20%3D%20PlayerInput%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22abc%22.to_string()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20player%20%3D%20handler.handle(%26new_player_input).await%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20dbg!(player)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(())%0A%7D%0A)

```
diff --git a/src/main.rs b/src/main.rs
index 89fc611..6f7d375 100644
--- a/src/main.rs
+++ b/src/main.rs
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin, sync::Arc};
 
+use tokio::sync::Mutex;
+
 pub trait Trait: Send + Sync + Player + Shirt {}
 
 impl<T: Player + Shirt> Trait for T {}
@@ -42,12 +44,19 @@ impl Player for Repo {
         _input: &PlayerInput,
         lambda: &Lambda<'_, PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'a>, DomainPlayer>,
     ) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String> {
-        let mut tx = self.pool.begin().await.unwrap();
+        let tx = Arc::new(Mutex::new(self.pool.begin().await.unwrap()));
 
         // use _input here
 
-        let shirt_next_value = Box::new(|model: String| {
-            self::Shirt::shirt_get_next_and_increase(self, &mut tx, model)
+        let shirt_next_value = Box::new({
+            let tx = tx.clone();
+            move |model: String| -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<i64, std::string::String>> + Send>> {
+                let tx = tx.clone();
+                Box::pin(async move {
+                    self::Shirt::shirt_get_next_and_increase(self, &mut *tx.lock().await, model)
+                        .await
+                })
+            }
         });
 
         let domain_player = lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs { shirt_next_value }).await?;
@@ -56,7 +65,7 @@ impl Player for Repo {
             sqlx::query_as::<_, DomainPlayer>("INSERT INTO player (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *")
                 .bind(domain_player.id)
                 .bind(domain_player.shirt_number)
-                .fetch_one(&mut *tx)
+                .fetch_one(&mut *tx.lock().await)
                 .await
                 .unwrap();
```

Note that because a `&mut PgConenction` is passed to `shirt_get_next_and_increase` inside the async block, which references the `MutexGuard<Transaction<...>>` returned by `tx.lock().await`, the MutexGuard will be held until `shirt_get_next_and_increase` completes, even while it yeilds (if it yields). This shouldn't be an issue in this code, since it appears to be mostly sequential, and does not access `tx` until `shirt_get_next_and_increase` has completed. If this is not what you want, (i.e. if your actual code *does* access `tx` concurrently while `shirt_get_next_and_increase` is running) you could instead have `shirt_get_next_and_increase` take a `&Mutex<Transaction<...>>`, and only have it hold the lock when it needs to access the connection.

---

An sketch of an alternate solution would be to restructure the code so that the `Transaction` is passed around by value in function arguments and return values, e.g.

```rs
pub type Lambda<'a, ArgT, ResT> =
    dyn Fn(ArgT) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(ResT, ArgT), String>> + Send + 'a>> + Sync + 'a;
// ...
async fn shirt_get_next_and_increase<'a>(
    &'a self,
    mut tx: sqlx::Transaction<'static, sqlx::PgConnection>,
    _model: String,
) -> Result<(i64, sqlx::Transaction<'static, sqlx::PgConnection>), String> {
    // ...
    Ok((value, tx))
}
```

This could resolve the borrowing and shared-mutability issues, but may make the API more cumbersome, and may be infeasible for other reasons.

Comment: Cross-posted my answer from the discord server the question was cross-posted to.

Comment: Your code and your kindness in understanding the problem and even solving it with an alternative almost makes me cry with joy. THANK YOU! I'm studying what you wrote...

Comment: 2 small questions:

1. Why do we need to use `-> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<i64, std::string::String>> + Send>>`, isn't this inferred? And why not?

2. After the `INSERT` code I have `tx.commit().await?;` which now I'm trying to use with Mutex's `lock()` (`tx.lock().await.commit().await.unwrap();`) but I'm having error like: `cannot move out of dereference of OwnedMutexGuard<Transaction<'_, Postgres>>`. What should I use for the commit() method?

Comment: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/t37y39

Comment: You'd need to `Arc::try_unwrap(tx).unwrap().into_inner().commit().await.unwrap()`. You can only commit the Transaction if you have sole (not shared) ownership, so you need to "take it out" of the Arc and Mutex before you can do that. `Arc::try_unwrap(tx).unwrap()` will panic if there are other shared owners still.   The return type may be inferred, I added it while debugging and didn't remove it. I'm not at a computer at the moment so I can't check

Comment: Alternately you could use an `Arx<Mutex<Option<Transaction>>>`, then `lock().await.take().unwrap().commit().await;`, but you'd need to change the other places you use it without taking it out, from `.lock().await` to `.lock().await.as_mut().unwrap()`

Comment: Why do we need to use `-> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<i64, std::string::String>> + Send>>`, isn't this inferred? And why not?

Comment: Everything worked even in my real project. The last thing is how to remove the ugly `-> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<i64, std::string::String>> + Send>>`.

Comment: If I remove it the error is: `note: expected struct Pin<Box<dyn std::future::Future<Output = Result<i64, common::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send>> found struct Pin<Box<impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<i64, common::error::Error>>>>`